# Create a variable and specify type with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have some code which calculates `prevPageNo`. It's using a React hook but I don't think that's importnat for this question:

```
  const prevPageNoRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    prevPageNoRef.current = pageNo;
  });
  const prevPageNo = prevPageNoRef.current;
```

How can I specify the type of `prevPageNo`? So something like this:

```
  const prevPageNo:number = prevPageNoRef.current;
```

Comment: A naive observation perhaps but I think the syntax you are using is correct.

Comment: That's weird. If I change it to prevPageNo:string and use this feature it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: You could write: `const prevPageNoRef: { current: number } = useRef();`

Comment: Please consider editing the code in this question to constitute a [mcve].  Such code should demonstrate your issue in a standalone environment with no external dependencies like react (assuming that react isn't important for this question as you say).   It should be code you can drop into, say, [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and see your issue and only your issue.  If you do this, it will improve your chances of getting a relevant answer, since otherwise all people can do is make guesses.  Good luck!